# converting PDF to PNG with imagick and HTML input

Tags: html, pdf, png, imagick

I am trying to upload a Document (PDF) using HTML , and using imagick to convert it to a PNG if some one can look at my code and help me out I would greatly appreciate it, Thank You!!!

Also when I try to upload my document PDF thru  I get a error message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$image' (T_VARIABLE) in 
C:\projects\magick2.php on line 27
```

Line 27 is associated with this code    `$image->setImageFormat('png')`

```
<!DOCTYPE htlm>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>TEST!!!</title>

</head>

<div id = "cont">
<form method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action =     "magick2.php">
<div id = "choose">
File:

    <input type="file" name="image" size = "40" id = "fimage" accept =  "application/pdf">
    <input type="submit" value="UpLoad" name = "wang">  
</div>
</form>
</div>

<?php

$image = new Imagick();

$image->readImage(string ($_POST['wang'])

$image->setImageFormat('png');

$image->writeImage('C:\projects\matt.png');

$img = $image;

    echo "<img src = matt.png >"; 

$img->clear(); 

$img->destroy();

?>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going in to much details, but the actual reason for that error message is 'missing semi colon on the line above it'.

```
$image->readImage(string ($_POST['wang'])
```

Answer (score -1):

you should receive "image" instead of "wang"

```
$image->readImage(string ($_POST['image'])
```